# Always have focus policy on hidden widget? (Qt C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

I am learning to process keypress and keyrelease events in Qt (C++).  I have a class Keyboard with which I want to process all of these events.  It inherits QObject.  It doesn't need to process any mouse events.  I am trying to figure out how I can direct all of the keyboard input when my application is open to that class.

I've tried adding it as a widget in a layout of my MainWindow class and hiding it (the widget, not the layout).  Currently, that is not responding.

I've also tried this in my MainWindow class:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    keys->keyPressEvent(event); 
    //Keys is a Keyboard object with this public method:
    //void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
}
```

But that's not working either.  In my Keyboard::Keyboard() constructor, I have:

```
this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
```

I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do to make sure the keyboard input gets there.

If someone knows a way to send all keyboard events to this class for my Qt application, it would be *very* helpful!

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know, I found the answer to my question.

In the constructor for the class that is handling my keyboard events, I added this line:

```
QWidget::grabKeyboard();
```

and now all the keyboard input when that application is active goes straight to that widget.
You can check the reference for more information:
[QWidget::grabKeyboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html).

Note: nothing else (i.e., no other widgets) will get keyboard input until you call `QWidget::releaseKeyboard()`.